# Inkscape: Complete Path with Object

Tags: inkscape, svg

Example: I have a Circle and on top of that a Path.

The Path touches the Circle at both Ends and forms some shape inside the circle.
I now want to complete the Shape with the Edge of the Circle so that the shape is completed to a whole.

How would i do this? See example image if my description was bad.

[Before & What i Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlxDI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps would be as follows:

1. Duplicate the green circle (with <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>), so you can keep the original.
2. Select the path and the new circle (it is important that your path is layered above the circle).
3. Do *Path -> Division*

This will divide the new circle into 2 shapes. Delete the unneeded section.

Documentation [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html).